# Display specific image from SQL database with image control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image

I have a search page that a user can use to search for certain information about a device (ex. computer) that has been entered into a SQL database. They can search for Brand, Type, Hard Drive Capacity and other things. Once they click the search button, results are displayed in a repeater control. The DeviceID for each device is clickable and when clicked, it takes the user to another page that has all the details about that certain device. I want to be able to display the image for that certain device on that page, as well as all the other information. I have the image being saved as Image type in my SQL database. But I can't figure out how to get it out of my database and display it on the page. I've tried a few different approaches including displaying it in a grid control, which didn't work. I also tried using ASHX files but couldn't quite figure that one out either. I am using C# and ASP.NET. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any code is needed, please let me know and I will be glad to post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First hit on Google:

**[Retrieve Images from a SQL database for display in an Asp.Net Datagrid](http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Was able to solve this kind of issue using a Handler (ASHX). there are a lot of samples online. try this .. http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Insert_Images_Database.aspx

Comment: I've tried this so many different times but I could never get it to work correctly. I think it had something to do with the ImageUrl. I was able to statically set an image and have it displayed, but for some annoying reason, I couldn't get the ASHX to work.