# ASP.NET C# Get retrieve and show image from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to retrieve an image from a SQL Server database and show in a `Image` tool.

I have this code

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="style2" Height="166px" Width="488px" />


SqlConnection connect = null;

string connectstring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=teste;Integrated Security=true;pooling=false";
connect = new SqlConnection(connectstring);
connect.Open();

string Scmd = "SELECT id, imagem where id = 2";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Scmd, connect);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    Label1.Text = reader[0].ToString();                        
    byte[] imagem = (byte[])(reader[1]);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagem);

    Image1.ImageUrl = ms.FromStream(ms); //i tried this
}
```

But I can't do this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = ms.FromStream(ms);
```

because I get an error.

Somebody please can help me? The only problem I have is show the image.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: the recommended way is to store the path to your image, so that once retrieved from the db, you can build the url to the image

Comment: You should be wrapping your `reader`, your `MemoryStream`, your `cmd` and your `connection` in `using` blocks.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question since you don't show how Image1 is declared.  Is this a web application?  If so then you will need a url.  You will also probably need a server to deliver the data from the database when that URL is accessed.  OR you could store the image as a file and use a standard url no service needed.

Comment: ...or write an ashx handler to fetch the image from the db and return it as a binary stream.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that saving a path of the picture is not a good idea, but okay :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140729/retrieve-image-from-database-and-display-on-asp-net-without-httphandler, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456052/display-specific-image-from-sql-database-with-image-control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate `base64string` out of byte array and use that as inline image source.

1. Convert to base64string. [Refer this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ```
> byte[] imagem = (byte[])(reader[1]);
> string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imagem) ;
> ```

2. Use this string as inline image like following. [Refer this](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

`Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",base64String);`

Assumption: image saved as `jpg`.

If this differs, then change line in step#2.

**Disclaimer:**  `Base64string` as image is suitable for small sized image , but if we have bigger image, then the string produced will have large sized string. Advantage is , browser don't have to request multiple times for each image ( if you implemented this as `image.src= "http://handler-to-image"`).

Comment: Of course, this just about doubles the download size of the image.

Comment: This solution reveals a horrible design.  This won't scale.