# How to show pictures in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, image, gridview

my pictures are stored in my database as binary data.

How can I show them in my itemtemplate tag in asp?

I established the network and everything needed.

for string data I'm using the following tags

```
<ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblProvider" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Provider") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

my column in the database is called Provider.

Now for the picture part, the column is called Picture,

this is ofcourse not working

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture" SortExpression="Picture" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblimage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Picture") %>' />
                     </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I show the picture in the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a HTTP handler for this. And use that handler as image source in `itemtemplate`. It would look like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <img id="Image1" src='PathToHandler.ashx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>' alt="img"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Note:** I am trying to pass `primary key` as `id` to handler, so that in handler you can retrive binary data using `id` from SQL table.

And in handler, use DB call to get binary data from SQL server using `id` in where condition. And write that to `Response.OutputStream`. Use following for response write a binary data ( image).

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // fill the memory stream and then write.
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

**OR**

I have already answered this similar type of question (but with different approach) - [ASP.NET C# Get retrieve and show image from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494505/asp-net-c-sharp-get-retrieve-and-show-image-from-sql-server-database/26494800#26494800)

Comment: this is not working, i created the handler, but for a reason i cant' pass eval, i put ImageUrl='PathToHandler.ashx?id=3' and it worked so my handler is working but i can't pass the id. in my handler, context.Request.QueryString("ImID").ToString() is returning "<%".. this is my error I'm trying to check my problem

Comment: UPDATE : this is not working, i created the handler, but for a reason i cant' pass eval, i put ImageUrl='PathToHandler.ashx?ImID=3' and it worked so my handler is working but i can't pass the id. in my handler, context.Request.QueryString("ImID").ToString() is returning "<%".. this is my error I'm trying to check my problem

Comment: Got it @FaresJosephEid , you can not pass `<% .. %>` to server control, need to discard that and use simple html control. I have updated my post, please use that